# PHPMailer sometimes send mails sometimes not. I use gmail smtp

Tags: phpmailer

I use PHPMailer  class to send letter and I use gmail account as smtp server.
problem is what sometimes it work well and visitors get letters, but sometimes no and show me error "Message body is empty" or like that.
I think if be problem in code, so don't sent any letter for websites visitors.
why happien like this? what can be problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Port = 465;
```

With:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Port = 587;
```

and hopefully all will be okay from now on.

Answer (score 0):

my code is

```
function mail_send($type, $id, $mailadd, $maillname) {
    global $lang;
    global $site_adress;
    global $pavadinimas;
    global $tekstas;
    global $ivadas;
    global $full_date;
    global $short_date;

    require_once ('includes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $siteuser_name = SQL_ROW("users", "WHERE user_id='1'", "user_name");
    $siteadminemail = SQL_ROW("users", "WHERE user_id='1'", "user_email");
    $alttext = users_langs(altmailtext);
    if ($type == "mailactiveletter") {
        $subj = users_langs("mailactivesubject");
        $linktur = "$site_adress/$lang/usermail_$type-$id.html#kat";
        //    var_dump($linktur,$type, $siteuser_name,$siteadminemail);
    }
    if ($type == "mailchangeadress") {
        $subj = users_langs("prisijduomenupriminimas");
        $linktur = "$site_adress/$lang/usermail_$type-$id.html#kat";
    }
    $body = file_get_contents("$linktur");
    $body = eregi_replace("[\]", '', $body);

    define('GUSER', 'uxxxx@gmail.com'); // Gmail username
    define('GPWD', 'xxx'); // Gmail password

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    //$mail->AddReplyTo("$siteadminemail", "$siteuser_name");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("no-replay@xxx.co.uk", "$siteuser_name");
    $mail->AddAddress("$mailadd", "$maillname");
    // $mail->SetFrom("$siteadminemail", "$siteuser_name");
    $mail->SetFrom("no-replay@xxx.co.uk", "$siteuser_name");
    // $mail->AddReplyTo("$mailadd", "$maillname");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("no-replay@xxx.co.uk", "$siteuser_name");

    $mail->Subject = "$subj";

    $mail->AltBody = "$alttext $linktur";
// optional, comment out and test
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a $mail->Sender property.

For exemple:
$mail->Sender is the same value of a $mail->From and I add the two lines.

$mail->From = "noreply@test.com";
$mail->Sender = "noreply@test.com";